# How to add custom product 'option' to container2?

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I have some two options added to products via the admin panel. What I want to do is insert some custom html between these options. Is it possible to do this programmatically ?

Something similar to:

```
$_product->addOption(
    array(
        'type' => 'html',
        'value' => '<!--html to go here-->',
        'position' => 1
    ) );
```

where the type would require a new view script that would just echo the option value.

Alternatively, is there a way to echo out the options independently? e.g.:

```
echo $_product->getOption(0)->toHtml(), // echo first option
     $myHtmlHere,                       // echo my html
     $_product->getOption(1)->toHtml(); // echo second option
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tim for pointing me in the right direction:

```
$_options = $_product->getOptions();
foreach($_options as $option)
{
    //radio, checkbox, select and multi-select all run off this class
    $o = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select();

    //Each product will save the option with its own ID. Every option has the same
    //name, so will check for that. If the right option, set it as a radio element
    if($option->getTitle() == 'Colour') {
        $option->setType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO);
    }

    //This class requires the option, product and layout instance to
    //work correctly.
    $o->setOption($option)
        ->setProduct($_product)
        ->setLayout($this->getLayout());

    //echo the element
    echo $o->getValuesHtml();
}
```

This does not echo the title of the option or wrap it in interesting HTML (no DDs).

I have altered the `foreach` loop to suit my needs but this is the code needed to echo the options I want.

Comment: Which file did you place this code in?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to loop through custom options of your product and then depending on option ID insert your custom HTML:

```
if($_product->hasOptions()) {
    foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $option) {
        echo $option->getOptionHtml();

        if ($option->getId() == [your-option-id]) {
            // output your custom HTML here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getOptionHtml` is returning null.

Comment: what is your option type?

Comment: The first is a checkbox, the second is a select.